# Send messages to clients at scale over APIGateway Websockets

Tags: websocket, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, scalability

We are working on a POC to send messages to clients/browsers over Websockets. We are using AWS APIGateway Websockets for it, after client requests a connection, the connection is created and id is stored in Dynamo DB. Whenever there is an update, AWS Lambda fetches all the connection ids from DDB and iterate over them and send message to clients over the websocket connections.

This solution works fine with less number of clients but fails at scale, because lambda has to iterate through large number of connections. Is there a support from APIGateway to broadcast messages to all clients about the updates, if not what approach can we take to support large number of clients using Websockets?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a support from APIGateway to broadcast messages to all clients about the updates

There has not been any way via the API Gateway API (at least the v3 javascript API) to send to client connections without [explicitly knowing the connection ID](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-apigatewaymanagementapi/classes/posttoconnectioncommand.html).

> what approach can we take to support large number of clients using Websockets?

Scanning DynamoDB is not ideal in terms of [cost or performance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-query-scan.html#bp-query-scan-performance). I've learned this the hard way.

I would consider either creating your own websocket server and hosting it via EC2 or switching your data storage to something outside of the traditional offerings of AWS, assuming your requirements are minimal (i.e., only needing to store connection IDs).

Answer (score 0):

I am working on a similar project (WebSocket API Gateway + DynamoDB + Lambda triggered by a FIFO SQS Queue to publish messages to the connected users) and I realized that what was slowing down everything when broadcasting the messages was the postToConnection method.

At first, I tried multithreading in python to make multiple calls in parallel but I soon realized it didn't change anything.

At some point, I realized that the memory setting for my Lambda was still the default 128mb. I was not hitting up the memory limit at all, but within the config page of the Lambda, I noticed this sentence:

> Your function is allocated CPU proportional to the memory configured.
>
> The Memory (MB) setting determines the amount of memory available for your
> Lambda function during invocation. Lambda allocates CPU power linearly
> in proportion to the amount of memory configured. At 1,769 MB, a
> function has the equivalent of one vCPU (one vCPU-second of credits
> per second. To increase or decrease the memory and CPU power allocated
> to your function, set a value between 128 MB and 10240 MB.

Upon increasing the memory setting (and CPU at the same time), I immediately noticed a huge boost in performance. I can't say what is the "ideal" setting for the number of connections, but just increasing it to 512mb made all the difference in our case.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for sharing your observation. May I ask how many users were you able to support with 128MB and how much after increasing to 512MB. I wanted to support about 150K users. I heard AWS AppSync can help.

Comment: @kevind I'm also implementing a chat application in this exact approach. How many concurrent users were you able to support with this setup?